# Search text matching a pattern inside an XML tag

Tags: sed, awk, grep, unix

I have a file which contains XML tags. Each line has a root element and a couple of sub elements into it. The structure resembles something like this

```
<document><title>some title1</title><abstract>Some abstract1</abstract></document>
<document><title>some title2</title><abstract>Some abstract2</abstract></document>
<document><title>some title3</title><abstract>Some abstract3</abstract></document>
<document><title>some title4</title><abstract>Some abstract4</abstract></document>
```

Now I have to find all lines where the  tag contains a particular word. eg: get all lines that contain abstract1 inside the `<abstract>` tag.

How to do it in either grep, awk or sed?

Comment: what do you want to match? `Some abstract1`?

Comment: Yes, or something like just `abstract1`, but it should be present inside the <abstract> tag

Comment: Seems like a mention of [this famous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) is probably in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/<abstract>[^<]*abstract1/p' input
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

```
    grep  -nir  "<abstract>.*word.*</abstract>" filename
```

Comment: This will give me all lines that contain "your word". But I want to find only lines that contain "your word" inside a particular tag like <abstract>.

Comment: The updated code works. But I have already accepted the other answer. So I was able to only upvote.